# Is it possible to create a motion event using drawTextOnPath?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm new to android programming and I'm making a word search game with a custom design. Is it possible to apply a motion event on the puzzle i made using drawTextOnPath?

Here is my code on the design. I declared the strings just to output the shape of the wordsearch grid:

```
public class Game1 extends Activity {

TextView closep;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.game1);
    RelativeLayout surface = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.middleSurface);
    surface.addView(new GraphicsView(this));

    ImageButton imagebutton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton1);
    imagebutton1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            initiatePopupWindow();
        }
    });

}

PopupWindow pwindow;

protected void initiatePopupWindow() {

    try {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) Game1.this
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pause_layout,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.playout));
        pwindow = new PopupWindow(layout, 480, 800, true);
        pwindow.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

        closep = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textBack);
        closep.setOnClickListener(cancel_button_click_listener);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private OnClickListener cancel_button_click_listener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        pwindow.dismiss();

    }
};

static public class GraphicsView extends View {
    private final String O = "O O O O O O O O O O O O E V O L O O A C T I O N A L O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O";
    private final String P = "O O O O O O O O O O O O O B O O M O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O";
    private final String Q = "O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O M O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O";
    private final String R = "O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O M O O O O O O O O O O O O O G O O G L E O O O O O O O O O O O O O";
    private final String S = "O O O O O O O O O O O O O N O O M O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O";
    private final String T = "O O O O O O O O O O O O O D O O M O O O O O O O O O O W A V E O O E G A G N E O O O O O O O O O O O O O O";
    private final String U = "O O O O O O O O O O O O O M O O S E O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O O";

    /*
     * private final char[] O_arr = O.toCharArray(); private final char[]
     * P_arr = P.toCharArray(); private final char[] Q_arr =
     * Q.toCharArray(); private final char[] R_arr = R.toCharArray();
     * private final char[] S_arr = S.toCharArray(); private final char[]
     * T_arr = T.toCharArray(); private final char[] U_arr =
     * U.toCharArray();
     */

    public GraphicsView(Context context) {
        super(context);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        this.setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
        float width = (float) getWidth();

        float height = (float) getHeight();

        float radius;

        if (width > height) {

            radius = height / 4;

        } else {

            radius = width / 4;

        }

        Path circle1 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle1.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 300),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Path circle2 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle2.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 200),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Path circle3 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle3.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 100),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Path circle4 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle4.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 50),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Path circle5 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle5.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 40),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Path circle6 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle6.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 30),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Path circle7 = new Path();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            circle7.addCircle(width / 2, height / 2, radius + (i * 20),
                    Path.Direction.CW);
        }

        Paint paint = new Paint();
        Paint xpaint = new Paint();
        Paint ypaint = new Paint();

        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        paint.setTextSize(30);
        paint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        xpaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        xpaint.setTextSize(30);
        xpaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        xpaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        xpaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        ypaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        ypaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        ypaint.setTextSize(30);
        ypaint.setStrokeWidth(2);
        ypaint.setTypeface(Typeface.SERIF);

        canvas.drawTextOnPath(U, circle7, -5 / 4 * (-47), -5 / 4 * (-47),
                ypaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(T, circle6, -5 / 4 * (-22), -5 / 4 * (-22),
                ypaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(S, circle5, -5 / 4 * (3), -5 / 4 * (3),
                ypaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(R, circle4, -5 / 4 * (25), -5 / 4 * (25),
                ypaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(Q, circle3, -5 / 4 * (50), -5 / 4 * (50),
                ypaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(P, circle2, -5 / 4 * (75), -5 / 4 * (75),
                xpaint);
        canvas.drawTextOnPath(O, circle1, -5 / 4 * (100), -5 / 4 * (100),
                paint);

        invalidate();

    }
```

Here is the output:
https://app.box.com/s/iuiggyq53ny40roxfp5j037r049r7yjw

Are there any other methods i could use to make it playable? Glad to have your help.

Comment: I dont really understand "apply a motion event on the puzzle i made using drawTextOnPath".  Can you provide more details?

Comment: i made a design using canvas but i still don't know how to apply the aligning highlight/crossing out of words in circular/curved motion. This is the output of the design https://app.box.com/s/iuiggyq53ny40roxfp5j037r049r7yjw

Comment: I guess you should use [Canvas.drawArc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawArc%28float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20float,%20boolean,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) for highlighting/crossing out. Use [value animators](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.html) if by _motion_ you mean _animation_. You can animate starting points or angles.

Comment: @torque203 thanks i have use the Canvas.drawArc to draw for the circles for the highlighting. Now my problem is on the onTouch event. Whenever i swipe from left to right all of the lines are highlighting in sync.